# Get convex polygons from vertex

Tags: polygon, path-finding, vertex, convex

Im writing a game in XNA and Im working right now in the pathfinding of the AI.

In my map there are some circular obstacles and I would like to use the mesh navigation technique (http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/NavigationMeshReference.html) so previously I need to convert those obstacles in a set of convex polygons.

Something like this:
[image]

Ive been searching in google for long time but couldnt find how to do it. Any clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems like that's a good starting place, then remove edges as long as the resulting shape remains convex.

Comment: Yay! that was exactly what I was looking for! So I can get then the Voronoi diagram. Thanks Jason